# How can I group dates by month and year with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a jquery solution to sort dates:

```
   <ul id="mainList">
        <li><span class="date">2012 05 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
        <li><span class="date">2011 05 02</span><p>Text...</p></li>
        <li><span class="date">2011 05 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
        <li><span class="date">2011 04 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
        <li><span class="date">2011 04 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
        <li><span class="date">2010 03 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
        <li><span class="date">2009 02 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    </ul>
```

and the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
// Month number to string
        var months = ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni','Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'];

// Sorting the <li> by year
$("#mainList li").sort(function(a,b) {
    var yearA = $(a).children("span").text().split(" ")[0],
        yearB = $(b).children("span").text().split(" ")[0];
    return yearA < yearB;
}).appendTo($("#mainList"));

// Grouping the <li> by year
$("#mainList li").each(function() {
    var year = $(this).children("span").text().split(" ")[0];
    // If the grouping <li> doesn't exist, create it
    if ($("#mainList li.year." + year).length === 0) {
        $("#mainList").append($('<li class="year ' + year + '">' + year + '<ul></ul></li>'));
    }
    // Add the current <li> to the corresponding grouping <li>
    $(this).appendTo($("#mainList li.year." + year + " ul"));
});

// Sorting the <li> by month inside each grouping <li>
$("#mainList li.year ul").each(function() {
    $(this).children("li").sort(function(a,b) {
        var monthA = $(a).children("span").text().split(" ")[1],
            monthB = $(b).children("span").text().split(" ")[1];
        return monthA < monthB;
    }).appendTo($(this));
});

// Grouping the <li> by month inside each grouping <li>
$("#mainList li.year ul").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.children("li").each(function() {
        var month = $(this).children("span").text().split(" ")[1];
        // If the grouping <li> doesn't exist, create it
        if ($this.find("li.month." + month).length === 0) {
            $this.append($('<li class="month ' + month + '">' + months[month-1] + '<ul></ul></li>'));
        }
        // Add the current <li> to the corresponding grouping <li>
        $(this).appendTo($this.find("li.month." + month + " ul")).addClass("item");
    });
});





});

</script>
```

The result is:

- 2012

  - Mai

    - 2012 05 01
    - Text...
- 2011

  - Mai

    - 2011 05 02
    - Text...
    - 2011 05 02
    - Text...
  - April

    - 2011 04 01
    - Text...
    - 2011 04 01
    - Text...
- 2010

  - März

    - 2010 03 01
    - Text...
- 2009

  - Februar

    - 2009 02 01
    - Text...

I try to make a change in the code but it doesn't work out. So actually I do not need the "year group". I only need the month group but with the year behind. The result should in the end look like this:

- Mai 2012

  - 2012 05 01
  - Text...
- Mai 2011

  - 2011 05 02
  - Text...
  - 2011 05 02
  - Text...
- April 2011

  - 2011 04 01
  - Text...
  - 2011 04 01
  - Text...
- März 2010

  - 2010 03 01
  - Text...
- Februar 2009

  - 2009 02 01
  - Text...

I tried to remove the code for the year and changed the code for the month:

```
 $this.append($('<li class="month ' + month + '">' + months[month-1] + year +'<ul></ul></li>'));
```

But everything I try I have difficulties to achieve the result I wish.

Comment: How do you populate `mainList` in the first place?  I suspect this may be better handled server-side, before adding the items to the list.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XbQ8t/5/ by Ihan (http://stackoverflow.com/users/592301/lhan)

Comment: @devin: actually the code works very nice, I only need to make the one little change, and cannot get it run ;'-o

Comment: If that's a reply to my question -- the fiddle doesn't show how you get the list items in `mainList` in the first place.  The fiddle has a static set of list items, which I'm assuming isn't actually your scenario (because in that case, you'd just hard code the list items in the order you need, using optgroup group designations).  The sort code may work nicely for you, but that doesn't mean it's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I did not make use of the solution you are working with and decided to do it from the scratch. The implementation is very simple and straight. I would not say this is the best way to do it but should do the job you need.

```
    var months = ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni','Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'];

$('#mainList li').each(function()
{
  var yearAppended = false;
  $('#mainList li').each(function()
  {
     var current = $(this);
     var next = $(this).next('li');
     if(next != undefined)
     {
        var currArr = current.find('span').text().split(' ');
        var nextArr = next.find('span').text().split(' ');  
        if(nextArr[0] > currArr[0]) // year comparison
        {
          current.insertAfter(next);   
        }   
        else if(nextArr[0] >= currArr[0] && nextArr[1] > currArr[1]) // month comparison
        {
           current.insertAfter(next);
        }
        else if(nextArr[0] >= currArr[0] && nextArr[1] >= currArr[1] && nextArr[2] > currArr[2]) // day comparison
        {
           current.insertAfter(next);
        } 
      }
  });
});

var currentYear = "";
var currentMonth = "";
$('#mainList li').each(function()
  {      

        var current = $(this);
        var currArr = current.find('span').text().split(' ');
        var monthIndex = currArr[1].length > 2 ? currArr[1] : currArr[1].substring(1,2);
        monthIndex--;
        if(currentYear == "" || currentYear != currArr[0])
        {     
            currentYear = currArr[0];
            currentMonth = currArr[1];
            current.wrap('<li>' + months[monthIndex] + " " + currArr[0] + '</li>');
        }
        else if(currentMonth == "" || currentMonth != currArr[1])
        {    
            currentMonth = currArr[1];            
            current.wrap('<li>' + months[monthIndex] + " " + currArr[0] + '</li>');
        }
  });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/08qyom1a/3/

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :)

Comment: Sorry, I tested your code, and it seem not to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/08qyom1a/2/

Comment: Oops. Forgot to include one condition. Updated solution and fiddle. Try again.